# Right Join onto df with factor for all rows, cannot get in right order even after creating ordered factor

Tags: r

A dataframe:

```
summary_table %>% dput
structure(list(rowname = c("Sessions", "Trial Sign Ups", "Total Site Conversions", 
"Site Conversion Rate", "Trial to Paid Conversion Rate"), `2021-07-01` = c(5076, 
19, 19, 0.00374310480693459, 0), `2021-07-02` = c(4810, 14, 14, 
0.00291060291060291, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looks like:

```
 summary_table
                        rowname   2021-07-01   2021-07-02
1                      Sessions 5.076000e+03 4.810000e+03
2                Trial Sign Ups 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
3        Total Site Conversions 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
4          Site Conversion Rate 3.743105e-03 2.910603e-03
5 Trial to Paid Conversion Rate 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

I need to amend this table so that it always has certain rows which are missing here. Here they are:

```
rows <- c("Sessions", "Trial Sign Ups", "Direct to Paid", "Total Site Conversions", 
          "Expired Trials", "Trial to Paid",  "Site Conversion Rate", 
          "Trial to Paid Conversion Rate")
```

I tried creating a right join onto a newly made df for this purpose. In the case of joining onto missing rows, I make them all 0 as opposed to NA:

```
correctdf <-   summary_table %>% right_join(data.frame(rowname = factor(rows, levels = rows)), by = 'rowname') %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Looks like:

```
correctdf
                        rowname   2021-07-01   2021-07-02
1                      Sessions 5.076000e+03 4.810000e+03
2                Trial Sign Ups 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
3        Total Site Conversions 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
4          Site Conversion Rate 3.743105e-03 2.910603e-03
5 Trial to Paid Conversion Rate 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
6                Direct to Paid 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
7                Expired Trials 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
8                 Trial to Paid 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

Almost there except my rows are not in the desired order. I'd like them in the same order as they are defined in `rows <- c(...)` above.

Tried:

```
correctdf <-   summary_table %>% right_join(data.frame(rowname = factor(rows, levels = rows)), by = 'rowname') %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  arrange(rowname)
```

Looks like:

```
                        rowname   2021-07-01   2021-07-02
1                Direct to Paid 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
2                Expired Trials 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
3                      Sessions 5.076000e+03 4.810000e+03
4          Site Conversion Rate 3.743105e-03 2.910603e-03
5        Total Site Conversions 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
6                Trial Sign Ups 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
7                 Trial to Paid 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
8 Trial to Paid Conversion Rate 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

Expected the rows to be in order. E.g. the second to last row should be "Site Conversion Rate" not "Trial to Paid".

How can I arrange my correctdf by the rows in the order they are defined when I create rows? dplyr or tidyverse approach preferred but not essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `slice` combined with `match`:

```r
summary_table %>% 
  right_join(data.frame(rowname = factor(rows, levels = rows)), by = 'rowname') %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  slice(match(rows, rowname))
```

returns

```r
                        rowname   2021-07-01   2021-07-02
1                      Sessions 5.076000e+03 4.810000e+03
2                Trial Sign Ups 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
3                Direct to Paid 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
4        Total Site Conversions 1.900000e+01 1.400000e+01
5                Expired Trials 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
6                 Trial to Paid 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
7          Site Conversion Rate 3.743105e-03 2.910603e-03
8 Trial to Paid Conversion Rate 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```